# IPictureDisp python

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32

I try to write com addIn for Inventor in python language. All works fine, except `ControlDefinitions.AddButtonDefinition` method, It needs an `IPictureDisp` type image.

How to get an image of such type in python?

this is method signature

```
Sub AddButtonDefinition(DisplayName As String, InternalName As String, Classification As CommandTypesEnum, ByRef ClientId As [optional] VARIANT, ByRef DescriptionText As [defaultvalue("")] BSTR, ByRef TooltipText As [defaultvalue("")] BSTR, ByRef StandardIcon As [optional] VARIANT, ByRef LargeIcon As [optional] VARIANT, ByRef ButtonDisplay As [defaultvalue(kDisplayTextInLearningMode)] ButtonDisplayEnum, Result As [out, retval] ButtonDefinition*)
```

this is code example from tutorial

```
Dim oControlDefinitions As ControlDefinitions
Set oControlDefinitions = oApp.CommandManager.ControlDefinitions

Dim oLargeIcon As IPictureDisp
Dim oSmallIcon As IPictureDisp
Set oLargeIcon = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Large.ico")
Set oSmallIcon = LoadPicture(App.Path & "\Small.ico")

Set oButtonDefinition = oControlDefinitions.AddButtonDefinition( _
  "Display Name", "invrSampleCommand", _
  kShapeEditCmdType, "CLSID of the AddIn", _
  "Description Text", "Tooltip", _
  oSmallIcon, oLargeIcon, _
  kDisplayTextInLearningMode)
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: https://github.com/S-Rx/PythonInventorAddIn  but it has nothing about button creation